# What does the phrase "fall foul of " come from?

Tags: phrase-origin

As [The Merriam Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fall%20foul%20of) says it means to to get into trouble because of failing to do what is required by (the law, a rule, etc.) For example:

> After leaving school she fell foul of the law and spent time in jail.

I have been trying to find something on its origin on the internet, but I cannot find anything. To me as a non-native english speaker the phrase sounds so odd that I am desperate to find out its origin.

Comment: I haven't researched it yet, but it might have something to do with fouls in baseball.

Comment: The most common idiom is probably "fell afoul of the law".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [An Etymological Dictionary of Modern English](https://books.google.it/books?id=fj_CAgAAQBAJ&pg=RA1-PA594&lpg=RA1-PA594&dq=fall%20foul%20of%20etymology&source=bl&ots=LOlXosQwd3&sig=21FtLE7_YrxA_5_m_v6DEpHIsR8&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiviuid-ojcAhXS_aQKHVqfDkQQ6AEwCHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=fall%20foul%20of%20etymology&f=false)  the expression has a nautical origin meaning become entangled.

> When one ship impedes the progress of another; it falls foul of it. A foul anchor is when its own rope becomes entangled with itself.

and the AHD lists the following meanings:

***[fall foul/afoul:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fall+foul)***

> 1. Nautical To collide. Used of vessels.
> 2. To clash: fell foul of the law.

From the following sense of ***[foul](https://www.etymonline.com/word/foul)***:

> Meaning "become entangled" (chiefly nautical) is from 1832, probably from foul (adj.) in the sense "obstructed by anything fixed or attached" (late 15c.).

(Etymonline)